# Getting INVALID_REQUEST Nack from GCM when using token based on IdentityId

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending downstream message via XMPP to GCM. GCM returns Nack with INVALID_REQUEST. What is wrong?

JSON request:
`{
"to":"di3gR2FnkqU:APA91bFVzCMvkcp14ul9S8dg145D4ahjk_Pdieuh5-Yo-lmS_wB59bAzLmRdo7e5g-lVEkLHA1WnMJt3iw49jWwXymivhuK8sVFs9bF3gY9HwqSJM7zCr2iDXxrmOeB9qIhnVC8URFcg",
"message_id":"3e2601b5-b346-4f10-a098-0752f2bd4121",
"data":{"payload":""},
"delivery_receipt_requested":false
}`

XMPP packet:
`<message id='X99Mc-12'><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">                {&quot;to&quot;:&quot;di3gR2FnkqU:APA91bFVzCMvkcp14ul9S8dg145D4ahjk_Pdieuh5-Yo-lmS_wB59bAzLmRdo7e5g-lVEkLHA1WnMJt3iw49jWwXymivhuK8sVFs9bF3gY9HwqSJM7zCr2iDXxrmOeB9qIhnVC8URFcg&quot;,&quot;message_id&quot;:&quot;3e2601b5-b346-4f10-a098-0752f2bd4121&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;payload&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;delivery_receipt_requested&quot;:false}</gcm></message>`

GCM response:
`{"message_id":"3e2601b5-b346-4f10-a098-0752f2bd4121",
"from":"di3gR2FnkqU:APA91bFVzCMvkcp14ul9S8dg145D4ahjk_Pdieuh5-Yo-lmS_wB59bAzLmRdo7e5g-lVEkLHA1WnMJt3iw49jWwXymivhuK8sVFs9bF3gY9HwqSJM7zCr2iDXxrmOeB9qIhnVC8URFcg",
"error_description":"",
"error":"INVALID_REQUEST",
"message_type":"nack"}`

Answer (score 0):

The client application was using incorrect package name. The used package name was different from the one set when enabling Google services for the App at https://developers.google.com/mobile/add.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are sending the right message structure or the required params.

I don't know if it can help but try to send this message with the "dry_run" param (used for testing your message without sending it to a real device).